# Accordionpane hide individual content independently

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, accordion

I have an Accordion pane called library and sub menus as book reserve, request and review
as shown below

```
   <asp:AccordionPane ID="Library" runat="server">

      <Header><div  >Library </div> </Header>
        <Content><div >Book Reserve</a></div>
                 <div >Book Request</a></div>
                 <div >Book Review</a></div>

        </Content>
     </asp:AccordionPane>
```

and from code behind i can hide entire pane using

```
    Dim accpane As AccordionPane
    accpane = Master.FindControl("Library")
```

but is there a way to hide the sub menu items i.e.. Reserve , request, review independently
something like `accpane("Book Request").visible = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to change the DIV element to:

```
<div id="X" runat="server">Book Request</a></div>
```

And use FindControl on the accordion pane to get the reference to it, and set Visible to false.  I forget the exact type of control that comes back; it may be HtmlGenericControl... not 100% sure.

Comment: Legend, thanx, was working on it for ages, it was                      Dim div As   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = accpane.FindControl("X") ;{\n}                                   div.Visible ="false"